# JSPM is not updating the package.json file

Tags: npm, aurelia, jspm, package.json

I'm trying to update some Aurelia packages with jspm.io, but when run:

```
jspm update aurelia-framework
```

I see in the console that new packages are downloaded and installed.
The config.js file is updated and the new aurelia-framework version is mapped.

Unfortunately the package.json file is not updated and it stays with the older version of the package.

Is this a bug in jspm or I'm missing something?
My jspm version is:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "jspm": "0.16.15",
}
```

Comment: You should probably update to the latest version of jspm to see if that fixes the issue. `npm install --save-dev jspm@latest` should give you the latest 0.16 version.

Comment: also jspm update wouldn't update dev dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I just had something similar. My packages in my actual jspmpackages folder were up to date but the config file and packages.json were not updating. It was quite amateur on my part though i think i had run the jspm install aurelia-framework at the wrong level in my directory. I went back to the root directory and ran jspm install, which overwrote my packages to the older versions that were in my config.js and packages.json. Then when i ran

```
jspm install aurelia-framework
```

everything worked fine. Then ran it for all the other dependencies and it worked fine too. Potentially just my error for being an idiot, but hope it helps